# How to use SqlBulkCopy and track Bulk Inserts with Glimpse

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, glimpse

In our app we use the `SqlBulkCopy` class to facilitate bulk loading of our database. Recently, I've tried to add Glimpse to our solution but the code fails with an invalid cast:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

This is because Glimpse ADO is using a wrapped `SqlConnection` to make its magic possible. Unfortunately, `SqlBulkCopy` requires a `SqlConnection` so I need to cast the `DbConnection`.

Is there no out-of-the-box way to profile bulk insertions? The only work-around I came across with so far is:

```
(SqlConnection)((GlimpseDbConnection)dbConnection).InnerConnection
```

It's ugly since it requires referencing GlimpseDbConnection explicitly and probably it also requires adding custom time-line events to get some tracing.
Is there no Glimpse add-on that solves this?

Comment: There is not one that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this approach (with EntityFramework's `DbContext`) and it seems to work:

```
DbContext Db = /* ... */;

var glimpseDbConnection = Db.Database.Connection as GlimpseDbConnection;
var sqlConnection = glimpseDbConnection != null ? (SqlConnection)glimpseDbConnection.InnerConnection : (SqlConnection)Db.Database.Connection;

var glimpseDbTransaction = Db.Database.CurrentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction as GlimpseDbTransaction;
var sqlTransaction = glimpseDbTransaction != null ? (SqlTransaction)glimpseDbTransaction.InnerTransaction : (SqlTransaction)Db.Database.CurrentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction;

using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, sqlTransaction))
{
    var dataTable = /* ... */;
    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 2000;
    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).Seconds;
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = /* ... */;
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```